# Can you change the contents of a (immutable) string via an unsafe method?

Tags: c#

I know that strings are immutable and any changes to a string simply creates a new string in memory (and marks the old one as free). However, I'm wondering if my logic below is sound in that you actually can, in a round-a-bout fashion, modify the contents of a string.

```
const string baseString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!";

//initialize a new string
string candidateString = new string('\0', baseString.Length);

//Pin the string
GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(candidateString, GCHandleType.Pinned);

//Copy the contents of the base string to the candidate string
unsafe
{
    char* cCandidateString = (char*) gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < baseString.Length; i++)
    {
        cCandidateString[i] = baseString[i];
    }
}
```

Does this approach indeed change the contents `candidateString` (without creating a new candidateString in memory) or does the runtime see through my tricks and treat it as a normal string?

Comment: Run the code and find out for yourself what happens.

Comment: Because I can only see the end results and not what's happening in memory.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `cCandidateString[i] = baseString[i]` and watch `candidateString` change as you play through each iteration.  Fun stuff!

Comment: Yes, no problem.  Unsafe code is, you know, unsafe.  It doesn't require the *unsafe* keyword either, fumbling a [DllImport] and declaring string where StringBuilder is needed gets it done too.  Pretty hilarious when you pass a string literal.  It was once even possible to change String.Empty with Reflection, they put a stop to that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your example works just fine, thanks to several elements:

- `candidateString` lives in the managed heap, so it's safe to modify. Compare this with `baseString`, which is interned. If you try to modify the interned string, unexpected things may happen. There's no guarantee that string won't live in write-protected memory at some point, although it seems to work today. That would be pretty similar to assigning a constant string to a `char*` variable in C and then modifying it. In C, that's undefined behavior.
- You preallocate enough space in `candidateString` - so you're not overflowing the buffer.
- Character data is *not* stored at offset 0 of the `String` class. It's stored at an offset equal to `RuntimeHelpers.OffsetToStringData`.

  ```
  public static int OffsetToStringData
  {
      // This offset is baked in by string indexer intrinsic, so there is no harm
      // in getting it baked in here as well.
      [System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable] 
      get {
          // Number of bytes from the address pointed to by a reference to
          // a String to the first 16-bit character in the String.  Skip 
          // over the MethodTable pointer, & String 
          // length.  Of course, the String reference points to the memory 
          // after the sync block, so don't count that.  
          // This property allows C#'s fixed statement to work on Strings.
          // On 64 bit platforms, this should be 12 (8+4) and on 32 bit 8 (4+4).
  #if WIN32
          return 8;
  #else
          return 12;
  #endif // WIN32
      }
  }
  ```

  Except...
- `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject` is **special cased** for two types: `string` and array types. Instead of returning the address of the object itself, it lies and returns the offset to the data. See the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/vm/marshalnative.cpp#L800) in CoreCLR.

  ```cpp
  // Get the address of a pinned object referenced by the supplied pinned
  // handle.  This routine assumes the handle is pinned and does not check.
  FCIMPL1(LPVOID, MarshalNative::GCHandleInternalAddrOfPinnedObject, OBJECTHANDLE handle)
  {
      FCALL_CONTRACT;

      LPVOID p;
      OBJECTREF objRef = ObjectFromHandle(handle);

      if (objRef == NULL)
      {
          p = NULL;
      }
      else
      {
          // Get the interior pointer for the supported pinned types.
          if (objRef->GetMethodTable() == g_pStringClass)
              p = ((*(StringObject **)&objRef))->GetBuffer();
          else if (objRef->GetMethodTable()->IsArray())
              p = (*((ArrayBase**)&objRef))->GetDataPtr();
          else
              p = objRef->GetData();
      }

      return p;
  }
  FCIMPLEND
  ```

In summary, the runtime lets you play with its data and doesn't complain. You're using `unsafe` code after all. I've seen worse runtime messing than that, including creating reference types on the stack ;-)

Just remember to add one additional `\0` *after* all the characters (at offset `Length`) if your final string is shorter than what's allocated. This won't overflow, each string has an implicit null character at the end to ease interop scenarios.

---

Now take a look at how `StringBuilder` creates a string, here's [`StringBuilder.ToString`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/mscorlib/src/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs#L327):

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public override String ToString() {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);

    VerifyClassInvariant();

    if (Length == 0)
        return String.Empty;

    string ret = string.FastAllocateString(Length);
    StringBuilder chunk = this;
    unsafe {
        fixed (char* destinationPtr = ret)
        {
            do
            {
                if (chunk.m_ChunkLength > 0)
                {
                    // Copy these into local variables so that they are stable even in the presence of race conditions
                    char[] sourceArray = chunk.m_ChunkChars;
                    int chunkOffset = chunk.m_ChunkOffset;
                    int chunkLength = chunk.m_ChunkLength;

                    // Check that we will not overrun our boundaries. 
                    if ((uint)(chunkLength + chunkOffset) <= ret.Length && (uint)chunkLength <= (uint)sourceArray.Length)
                    {
                        fixed (char* sourcePtr = sourceArray)
                            string.wstrcpy(destinationPtr + chunkOffset, sourcePtr, chunkLength);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chunkLength", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Index"));
                    }
                }
                chunk = chunk.m_ChunkPrevious;
            } while (chunk != null);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Yes, it uses unsafe code, and yes, you can optimize yours by using `fixed`, as this type of pinning is *much* more lightweight than allocating a GC handle:

```
const string baseString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!";

//initialize a new string
string candidateString = new string('\0', baseString.Length);

//Copy the contents of the base string to the candidate string
unsafe
{
    fixed (char* cCandidateString = candidateString)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < baseString.Length; i++)
            cCandidateString[i] = baseString[i];
    }
}
```

When you use `fixed`, the GC only discovers an object needs to be pinned when it stumbles upon it during a collection. If there's no collection going on, the GC isn't even involved. When you use `GCHandle`, a handle is registered in the GC each time.

Comment: Do interned strings not also live in the managed heap? Certainly modifying an interned string would be bad because it's highly likely that other users of that string also have references to it, it will change the hash code of the string, etc, but I thought that was all a matter of data structure rather than object storage location.

Comment: @Random832 yes, but my point is that it's less safer due to the fact that the runtime *may in the future* store those in write-protected memory (for instance the memory mapped exe image where they come from). It doesn't seem write-protected today but nothing guarantees it'll last that way forever.

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out, mutating the `String` objects is useful in some rare cases. I give an example with a useful code snippet below.

**Use-case/background**

Although everyone should be a huge fan of the really excellent character **Encoding** support that .NET has always offered, sometimes it might be preferable to cut down that overhead, especially if doing a lot of roundtripping between 8-bit (legacy) characters and managed strings (i.e. typically interop scenarios).

As I hinted, `.NET` is particularly emphatic that you must explicitly specify a text `Encoding` for any/all conversions of non-Unicode character data to/from managed String objects. This rigorous control at the periphery is really commendable, since it ensures that once you have the string inside the managed runtime you never have to worry; everything is just Unicode (technically, [UCS-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Coded_Character_Set)).

For contrast, consider a certain other popular scripting language that famously botched this whole area, resulting in an ongoing saga of parallel `2.x` and `3.x` versions, all due to adding support for Unicode in the latter.

By enforcing Unicode once you're inside, `.NET` pushes all that mess to the interop boundary where it is done "once-and-for-all", but this philosophy entails that that encoding/decoding work is eager and exhaustive, as opposed to "lazy" and more under your program's control. Because of this, the .NET Encoding/Encoder classes can be a performance bottleneck. If you're moving lots of text from wide (Unicode) to simple fixed 7- or 8-bit narrow ANSI, ASCII, etc. (note I'm not talking about MBCS or UTF-8, where you'll want to use the Encoders!), the .NET encoding paradigm might seem like overkill.

Furthermore, it could be the case that you don't know, or don't care to, specify an `Encoding`. Maybe all you care about is fast and accurate round-tripping for that low-byte of a 16-bit `Char`. If you [look at the .NET source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/text/asciiencoding.cs), even the `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding` might be too bulky in some situations.

---

**The code snippet...**

> ***Thin String:*** 8-bit characters directly stored in a managed
> **String**, one 'thin char' per wide Unicode character, without
> bothering with character encoding/decoding during round-tripping.

All of these methods just ignore/strip the upper byte of each 16-bit `Unicode` character, transmitting only each low byte exactly as-is. Obviously, successful recovery of the Unicode text after a round-trip will only be possible if those upper bits aren't relevant.

```
/// <summary> Convert byte array to "thin string" </summary>
public static unsafe String ToThinString(this byte[] src)
{
    int c;
    var ret = String.Empty;
    if ((c = src.Length) > 0)
        fixed (char* dst = (ret = new String('\0', c)))
            do
                dst[--c] = (char)src[c];  // fill new String by in-situ mutation
            while (c > 0);

    return ret;
}
```

In the direction just shown, which is typically bringing native data ***in*** to managed, you often don't have the managed byte array, so rather than allocate a temporary one just for the purpose of calling this function, you can process the raw native bytes directly into a managed string. As before, this bypasses all character encoding.

The (obvious) range checks that would be needed in this unsafe function are elided for clarity:

```
public static unsafe String ToThinString(byte* pSrc, int c)
{
    var ret = String.Empty;
    if (c > 0)
        fixed (char* dst = (ret = new String('\0', c)))
            do
                dst[--c] = (char)pSrc[c];  // fill new String by in-situ mutation
            while (c > 0);

    return ret;
}
```

The advantage of `String` mutation here is that you avoid temporary allocations by writing directly to the final allocation. Even if you were to avoid the extra allocation by using `stackalloc`, there would be an unnecessary re-copying of the whole thing when you eventually call the `String(Char*, int, int)` constructor: clearly there's no way to associate data you just laboriously prepared with a `String` object that didn't exist until you were finished!

---

**For completeness...**

Here's the mirror-code which reverses operation to get back a byte array (even though this direction doesn't happen to illustrate the string-mutation technique). This is the direction you'd typically use to send Unicode text ***out*** of the managed `.NET` runtime, for use by a legacy app.

```
/// <summary> Convert "thin string" to byte array </summary>
public static unsafe byte[] ToByteArr(this String src)
{
    int c;
    byte[] ret = null;
    if ((c = src.Length) > 0)
        fixed (byte* dst = (ret = new byte[c]))
            do
                dst[--c] = (byte)src[c];
            while (c > 0);

    return ret ?? new byte[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested to change a string literal and the results are very scary

```
var f1 = "paul";
var f2 = "paul";

fixed (char* bla = f1)
{
    bla[0] = 'f';
}
```

This changes both `f1` and `f2` to "faul".

So i would never recommend to mess with the immutability of strings unless you
just created a new string instance and know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Remember the compiler recognizes that `f1` and `f2` point to the same string and this is why there is only one "paul" stored in memory.