# Converting string to pointer syntax

Tags: c#, .net

This compiles:

```
string s = "my string";
unsafe 
{
    fixed (char* ptr = s)
    {               
          // do some works
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
string s = "my string";
unsafe 
{
    fixed (char* ptr = (char*)s)
    {               
          // do some works
    }
}
```

> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'char*'

I cannot find the spot in the [c# spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) which allows the first syntax but prohibit the second. Can you help and point out where this is talked about?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted - looks like a good question to me; clear about what is expected, clear about the error etc. Looking in the spec now.

Comment: While Jon is looking at the spec, let me show you the [implementation side of things](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32465407/3764814). For short: the CLI kind of *lies* about the pointer to a `string` object and gives you the pointer to its first char instead (it also does so for arrays). Special cases in the runtime ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I came across this question while researching different implementations of `string.GetHashCode()` which is different in different versions of BCL and also different in Mono. In *some implementation* non zero `RuntimeHelpers.OffsetToStringData` is added to the pointer value before processing. This could mean that whether or not it points to the first character is version dependent.

Comment: @zespri that's interesting. I was surprised a bit by the implicit addition of `OffsetToStringData` myself a first (even though it makes sense), but if that's version-dependent it's... scary.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski in Mono in particular `OffsetToStringData` is added but it always seems to amount to zero. I wonder why. On an unrelated topic if you run GetHashCode on the same string in .net 2.0  .net 4.0 and mono you will get 3 different results. Starting from .net 4.5 you also have `UseRandomizedStringHashing` from app.config that affects how it's calculated once again.

Comment: Yeah I've read somewhere they have daily builds at MS which change the `GetHashCode` implementation for their internal testing to make sure they don't rely on it being stable. That doesn't surprise me at all, it's made on purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in section 18.6 of the spec - the `fixed` statement.

The relevant productions are:

> *fixed-statement*:
>     `fixed (` *pointer-type*   *fixed-pointer-declarators* `)` *embedded-statement*
>
> *fixed-pointer-declarator*:
>      *identifier* `=` *fixed-pointer-initializer*
>
> *fixed-pointer-initializer*:
>     `&` *variable-reference*
>     *expression*

You're trying to use the *expression* version. Now, while there *isn't* a normal "conversion as an expression* from `string` to `char *`, the spec calls out the `string` case, saying that a fixed-pointer-initializer can be:

> An expression of type `string`, provided the type `char*` is implicitly convertible to the pointer type given in the fixed statement. In this case, the initializer computes the address of the first character in the string, and the entire string is guaranteed to remain at a fixed address for the duration of the fixed statement. The behavior of the fixed statement is implementation-defined if the string expression is `null`.

So although it *looks* like you're just performing a normal variable declaration and using an implicit conversion from `string` to `char *`, you're really making use of a special case of what the expression in a *fixed-pointer-initializer* is allowed to be.