# Concatenate ReadOnlySpan<char>

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

Ok, .NET Core 2.1 has landed. With it we've gotten a new way to work with string data being `ReadOnlySpan<char>`. It's great at splitting string data, but what about combining the spans back together?

```
var hello = "Hello".AsSpan();
var space = " ".AsSpan();
var world = "World".AsSpan();

var result = ...; // How do I get "Hello World" out of the 3 above?
```

Comment: Spans generally refer to pre-existing memory. To do what you want, you'd essentially need to allocate a new string or char-array, and then overwrite them (yes, you can overwrite `string` - immutability is a lie) using the source spans. Concatenation isn't readily built in AFAIK.

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there any posts or articles talking about the overwriting of string?

Comment: How about writing your own wrapper that encapsulates list of span and overrides the indexer?

Comment: @OnurGumus to get a coherent API I need the `result` be either `ReadOnlySpan<char>` or `string`

Comment: @hazzik The documentation is sparse probably (I think it is undocumented)... But for example you can take a look at [string.Copy](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs#L3027) that modifies directly the internal value of the string using `Buffer.Memcpy` through wstrcpy. **The important thing** is that the string you modify must be newly allocated (with the `new String('\0', length)` constructor for example, or another constructor, or the `.Copy()`). See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32465407/613130)

Comment: @walterlv in the context of spans, you can trivially force a read-only span into a read-write span (read-only is also a lie); then you're already done - just mutate away. Prior to spans: `unsafe` is your friend `fixed(char* ptr = theString) { ptr[3] = 'f'; }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's worth mentioning that an overload for concatenating spans was added in .NET Core 3 and that support for .NET Core 2.1 ended on August 21, 2021 [[src](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)]. If you upgrade now then you can simply use *String.Concat*.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Concat_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__

```cs
var hello = "Hello".AsSpan();
var space = " ".AsSpan();
var world = "World".AsSpan();

// .NET Core 3+
var result = string.Concat(hello, space, world);
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example of how the .NET team internally handles this for [Path.Join](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/Path.cs#L542-L562):

```
private static unsafe string JoinInternal(ReadOnlySpan<char> first, ReadOnlySpan<char> second)
{
    Debug.Assert(first.Length > 0 && second.Length > 0, "should have dealt with empty paths");

    bool hasSeparator = PathInternal.IsDirectorySeparator(first[first.Length - 1])
        || PathInternal.IsDirectorySeparator(second[0]);

    fixed (char* f = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(first), s = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(second))
    {
        return string.Create(
            first.Length + second.Length + (hasSeparator ? 0 : 1),
            (First: (IntPtr)f, FirstLength: first.Length, Second: (IntPtr)s, SecondLength: second.Length, HasSeparator: hasSeparator),
            (destination, state) =>
            {
                new Span<char>((char*)state.First, state.FirstLength).CopyTo(destination);
                if (!state.HasSeparator)
                    destination[state.FirstLength] = PathInternal.DirectorySeparatorChar;
                new Span<char>((char*)state.Second, state.SecondLength).CopyTo(destination.Slice(state.FirstLength + (state.HasSeparator ? 0 : 1)));
            });
    }
}
```

If you'd like to avoid using `unsafe` and use something that's *maybe* easier to read, you could use something like:

```
public static ReadOnlySpan<char> Concat(this ReadOnlySpan<char> first, ReadOnlySpan<char> second)
{
    return new string(first.ToArray().Concat(second.ToArray()).ToArray()).AsSpan();
}

public static ReadOnlySpan<char> Concat(this string first, ReadOnlySpan<char> second)
{
    return new string(first.ToArray().Concat(second.ToArray()).ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

Using `ReadOnlySpan` is pretty low level and optimized for speed and so how you do it will likely depend on your own situation. But in many situations, it's probably fine to go back to `string` interpolation and `StringBuilder` (or don't convert to `ReadOnlySpan` at all). So

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
return sb
    .Append(hello)
    .Append(space)
    .Append(world)
    .ToString();
```

or

```
return $"{hello.ToString()}{space.ToString()}{world.ToString()}";
```

Answer (score 7):

You can acheive that with a buffer like this =>

```
var hello = "Hello".AsSpan();
var space = " ".AsSpan();
var world = "World".AsSpan();

// First allocate the buffer with the target size
char[] buffer = new char[hello.Length + space.Length + world.Length];
// "Convert" it to writable Span<char>
var span = new Span<char>(buffer);

// Then copy each span at the right position in the buffer
int index = 0;
hello.CopyTo(span.Slice(index, hello.Length));
index += hello.Length;

space.CopyTo(span.Slice(index, space.Length));
index += space.Length;

world.CopyTo(span.Slice(index, world.Length));

// Finality get back the string
string result = span.ToString();
```

You can optimize one again by using an arraypool to reuse the buffer

```
char[] buffer =  ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Rent(hello.Length + space.Length + world.Length);
// ...
ArrayPool<char>.Shared.Return(buffer);
```

Comment: ArrayPool does not give any benefits. In fact it is slower (for these strings) and allocates additional 8 bytes.

Comment: True, but in a long lived application it makes sense to use an ArrayPool so you don't have to reallocate those bytes over and over. It can make a significant difference depending upon the app.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use string.Concat, which accepts ReadOnlySpan as parameters. Here is the implementation taken from github

```
internal static unsafe string Concat(ReadOnlySpan<char> str0, ReadOnlySpan<char> str1, ReadOnlySpan<char> str2)
{
    var result = new string('\0', checked(str0.Length + str1.Length + str2.Length));
    fixed (char* resultPtr = result)
    {
        var resultSpan = new Span<char>(resultPtr, result.Length);

        str0.CopyTo(resultSpan);
        resultSpan = resultSpan.Slice(str0.Length);

        str1.CopyTo(resultSpan);
        resultSpan = resultSpan.Slice(str1.Length);

        str2.CopyTo(resultSpan);
    }
    return result;
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4f9ae42d861fcb4be2fcd5d3d55d5f227d30e723/src/libraries/Microsoft.IO.Redist/src/Microsoft/IO/StringExtensions.cs

Comment: Note that this implementation uses the _unsafe_ keyword and you can only use it by allowing unsafe code in the Properties page of your project (or by setting _AllowUnsafeBlocks_ to _true_ in your csproj file). That's usually not a good idea for business applications.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote and use use the following extension/tool methods to concatenate spans:

```cs
   ReadOnlySpan<T> otherSpan = ...
   T[] someArray = ...

   var myArray = someSpan.Concat(otherSpan, someArray, etc);
   var myArray2 = SpanTool.Concat(someArray, otherSpan, etc);
```

**SpanExtensions.cs**

```cs
    public static class SpanExtensions {

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static T[] Concat<T>(this ReadOnlySpan<T> span0, ReadOnlySpan<T> span1)
            => SpanTool.Concat(span0, span1);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static T[] Concat<T>(this ReadOnlySpan<T> span0, ReadOnlySpan<T> span1, ReadOnlySpan<T> span2)
            => SpanTool.Concat(span0, span1, span2);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static T[] Concat<T>(this ReadOnlySpan<T> span0, ReadOnlySpan<T> span1, ReadOnlySpan<T> span2, ReadOnlySpan<T> span3)
            => SpanTool.Concat(span0, span1, span2, span3);

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        public static T[] Concat<T>(this ReadOnlySpan<T> span0, ReadOnlySpan<T> span1, ReadOnlySpan<T> span2, ReadOnlySpan<T> span3, ReadOnlySpan<T> span4)
            => SpanTool.Concat(span0, span1, span2, span3, span4);

    }
```

**SpanTool.cs**

```cs
 public static class SpanTool {

        public static T[] Concat<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> span0) {
            var result = new T[span0.Length];
            span0.CopyTo(result);
            return result;
        }

        public static T[] Concat<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> span0, ReadOnlySpan<T> span1) {
            var result = new T[span0.Length + span1.Length];
            var resultSpan = result.AsSpan();
            span0.CopyTo(result);
            var from = span0.Length;
            span1.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            return result;
        }

        public static T[] Concat<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> span0, ReadOnlySpan<T> span1, ReadOnlySpan<T> span2) {
            var result = new T[span0.Length + span1.Length + span2.Length];
            var resultSpan = result.AsSpan();
            span0.CopyTo(result);
            var from = span0.Length;
            span1.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            from += span1.Length;
            span2.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            return result;
        }

        public static T[] Concat<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> span0, ReadOnlySpan<T> span1, ReadOnlySpan<T> span2, ReadOnlySpan<T> span3) {
            var result = new T[span0.Length + span1.Length + span2.Length + span3.Length];
            var resultSpan = result.AsSpan();
            span0.CopyTo(result);
            var from = span0.Length;
            span1.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            from += span1.Length;
            span2.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            from += span2.Length;
            span3.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            return result;
        }

        public static T[] Concat<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> span0, ReadOnlySpan<T> span1, ReadOnlySpan<T> span2, ReadOnlySpan<T> span3, ReadOnlySpan<T> span4) {
            var result = new T[span0.Length + span1.Length + span2.Length + span3.Length + span4.Length];
            var resultSpan = result.AsSpan();
            span0.CopyTo(result);
            var from = span0.Length;
            span1.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            from += span1.Length;
            span2.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            from += span2.Length;
            span3.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            from += span3.Length;
            span4.CopyTo(resultSpan.Slice(from));
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**DISCLAIMER** I just wrote this now for my project after the answers here were unsatisfactory. If any bugs, will edit later.

Comment: All these allocate arrays for the result - which is to be expected since [ReadOnly]Span only appears to be for contiguous memory. I wonder if there's a Span-like type for discontiguous regions of memory.

Answer (score 0):

By using nearly all solution provided as answers here, defeats readonlymemory and span's purpose: to not allocate/copy memory unless necessary.
This article explains in-depth how to join two or more spans into a sequence reader: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/creating-a-readonlysequence-from-array-data-in-dotnet.
Steve's post shows that it may be overkill and a Pipe/PipeReader/PipeWriter would suffice in nearly all common scenarios.

My scenario uses a IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory> to simulate a SequenceReader.
Please note that I can't go back after read, this is possible in both SequenceReader and Pipe.

My sample code:

```cs
// those strings are allocated only once and serves as example to reuse them in code.
private static ReadOnlyMemory<char> space = new[]{ ' ' };
private static ReadOnlyMemory<char> hello = "Hello".AsMemory();
private static ReadOnlyMemory<char> world = "World".AsMemory();
public IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> PrintHelloWorld(string concatValue)
{
    yield return hello;
    yield return space;
    yield return concatValue.AsMemory(); // because we receive string, we need to convert it to memory. That will copy string to a memory object containing its data. This will allocate string's length in memory, plus the struct size, all of them in stack.
    yield return space;
    yield return world;
}

public void PrintToConsole()
{
    foreach(var part in PrintHelloWorld("Stackoverflow"))
    {
        Console.Write(part);
    }

}
```

That works in a lot of scenarios (reading/writing streams mainly).

Answer (score -4):

My quick Friday afternoon thoughts:

```
var hello = "Hello";
var helloS = hello.AsSpan();
var spaceS = " ".AsSpan();
var worldS = "World".AsSpan();

var sentence = helloS.ToString() + spaceS.ToString() + worldS.ToString();

//Gives "Hello World"
```

At least according my quick play on LinqPad, and a quick read of the [System.Memory Source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Memory/tests/ReadOnlySpan/ToString.cs)

Comment: Context for why this is a bad solution: The idea of using Spans is to reduce the heap allocations. You lose this advantage by converting them to strings. However, this works.