# Is it legal to modify strings?

Tags: c#, string, language-lawyer, fixed, unsafe

Using a fixed statement one can have a pointer to a string. Using that pointer they can modify the string. But is it legally allowed in C# documentation?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "hello";
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (char* p = s)
            {
                p[1] = 'u';
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
        Console.Write("hello" + "\n");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

// hullo
// hello
```

The above program modifies a string literal.

Comment: If it compiles, it's legal. Whether it is good practice or not, that another discussion. But this is one of those idiosyncrasies of C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you change the contents of a (immutable) string via an unsafe method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464944/can-you-change-the-contents-of-a-immutable-string-via-an-unsafe-method)

Comment: @DavidG That's explicitly not true with `unsafe` and friends. The whole point of this is that lets you do things that aren't obviously safe but where you _claim_ that they're safe. Using them to break language invariants is _not_ a safe use.

Comment: The C# standard tends to not concern itself with low-level stuff like this; it assumes that you know what you're doing if you go `unsafe`. The runtime is not guaranteed to remain stable if you scribble over interned strings, however. (Or even to allow that at all -- a runtime could keep those on a read-only page and fault. Current implementations don't do that.)

Comment: @Cubic I never said it was safe, just that it was legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#the-fixed-statement):

> Modifying objects of managed type through fixed pointers can results *[sic]* in undefined behavior. For example, because strings are immutable, **it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the characters referenced by a pointer to a fixed string are not modified.**

(My **emphasis**)

So, it's explicitly contemplated within the language and you're not meant to do it, but it's *your* responsibility, not the compiler's.

Comment: Thanks for the simple complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Legal" may be the wrong word to use here. "Incorrect" is what I'd say. It's *possible*, but Strings are [defined as immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8) in C#. By mutating one anyway you're violating class invariants. The runtime may react to it anyway it pleases, including "apparently working", "falling over" or "stealing your credit card info to buy tacos"*. The whole point of the `unsafe` keyword is that you introduce a section of your code where you say "OK I know you can't show this is safe, but trust me I know what I'm doing and it totally is".

*: The more likely risk in this particular case is that somewhere between the compiler and runtime multiple stages would be perfectly justified in inlining and constant folding accesses to string literals, but not others depending on slight variations in the code, meaning you could get inconsistent results at runtime. The bottom line is, don't do this.

Comment: I would actually not be very concerned about the kind of inconsistency you sketch in your last paragraph -- the compiler will dutifully unify identical string literals into identical `ldstr` opcodes, and the runtime in turn guarantees that all such `ldstr` opcodes that refer to the same literal will get the same string object. As the spec says, "when two or more string literals that are equivalent according to the string equality operator [..] appear in the same program, these string literals refer to the same string instance". That still doesn't make this safe, of course.

Comment: I thought `legal` is compatible with language-lawyer tag. Well I know it not a good idea to change literal strings. But I asked the question to see if it is explicitly allowed in the documentation. Because C#  documentation explicitly allows to define a pointer to a string. What I'm asking if it allows to use that pointer to modify the string? Does it ban such usage? Or is it a UB?

Comment: @nano Strings are defined as immutable. You don't need a separate paragraph to explain that mutating something that is immutable is, in fact, not good.

Answer (score -2):

Legal is such as strong word, but yes, you can. I'll add one more thing, you don't use it unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: any suggestion for a less strong word?

Comment: Do you have an example of a situation where it is necessary? Edit: I can only think of writing some kind of exploit, so perhaps that is the example.