# How can I securely clear the contents of a TextBox using pointers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, security, pointers

I'm currently experimenting with making a password storage system in Windows Forms, and I heard that you should overwrite strings containing sensitive information as soon as possible once you're done using it. Since strings are immutable in C#, I decided to try clearing the two `TextBox`es containing the username and password using pointers. I tried two methods from [Can you change the contents of a (immutable) string via an unsafe method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464944/can-you-change-the-contents-of-a-immutable-string-via-an-unsafe-method) (OP's method and the accepted answer), but neither of them seemed able to clear the text from a `TextBox` (although they worked for ordinary strings); I also couldn't find any more answers on the internet. Is this an intended feature, or am I doing something wrong in my code? Is my method overkill? Does my method not work at all?

Code:

```
// First method that I tried
unsafe
{
    if (this.textBox1.Text != String.Empty)
        fixed (char* usr = this.textBox1.Text)
            for (int i = 0; i < this.textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
                usr[i] = '\0';
    if (this.textBox2.Text != String.Empty)
        fixed (char* pwd = this.textBox2.Text)
            for (int i = 0; i < this.textBox2.Text.Length; i++)
                pwd[i] = '\0';
}

// Second method that I tried
if (this.textBox1.Text != String.Empty)
{
    GCHandle gcU = GCHandle.Alloc(this.textBox1.Text, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    unsafe
    {
        char* usr = (char*)gcU.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
            usr[i] = '\0';
    }
    gcU.Free();
}
if (this.textBox2.Text != String.Empty)
{
    GCHandle gcP = GCHandle.Alloc(this.textBox1.Text, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    unsafe
    {
        char* pwd = (char*)gcP.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.textBox2.Text.Length; i++)
            pwd[i] = '\0';
    }
    gcP.Free();
}
```

Edit: In case anyone's wondering, I'm using .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: `Since strings are immutable in C#`, correct, but overwriting them and or assigning a new value will have no effect to be honest; you can still read the memory.

Comment: The question is what you want to achieve with this. If somebody (or some software) is able to read the process memory of your application, you're lost anyway. There's so much sensitive data in there, that leaking the password will be the least of your problems. One can also execute arbitrary code in that scenario.

Comment: You could use [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-5.0)

Comment: On the other hand, I do think that your solution will do what you expect it to. Did you test it (i.e. using the debugger) or why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @Codexer Well, I thought that overwriting the memory addresses would ignore the immutability of strings; the answer from the post I linked implied so.

Comment: @PMF I guess that's true. Are there ways to prevent that, or can that vulnerability only be introduced by a coding flaw? And yes, I did test it, with a `TextBox` and an ordinary `string`; it only worked with the `string`.

Comment: A program can still read the pixels :)

Comment: Well, the password would still be safe (unless there's a keylogger on the system...) I guess this is kind of overkill, then.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The documentation says that `SecureString` isn't recommended for new development. I'll still look into it, though.

Comment: @neondev1: with "new" development they mean .NET Core. This is a Winforms question and on windows the string is encrypted in memory and has not the limitations as on other platforms. However it's not 100% secure, it's just more secure than string.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah, thanks. I'll try to implement a control using it, then.

Comment: @neondev1 How an attacker would be able to "hijack" your application depends greatly on the application you're using. Typically, any attack vector that causes remote code execution can be used (i.e. surfing on infested sites, clicking malicious e-mail links) but of course also bugs in your own program.

Comment: Besides the bugs in the program, the other factors seem to affect any program, so I guess they're unpreventable. I also saw somewhere that some garbage collectors might leave copies of `String`s in memory, which could then be read by any process. Is this an issue in .NET?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally, data in memory can contain sensitive data. All data the program operates on needs to be in memory at some point, so of course there's also sensitive data in memory (not only passwords, but of course also the data you fetch using this password, user names, e-mail-addresses, etc.). It is (with more or less effort) possible to erase the data from memory as soon as it is no longer used, but that doesn't solve the issue really, it might just reduce the risk of leaking the data.

However, as I stated in the comments above, if somebody gets access to the program memory, security is compromised, and he or she can do whatever one wants with the program data and also start executing tasks with the permissions of the active user.

On Windows, debugging one's own programs is typically allowed, so any program that executes on a computer can (theoretically) read all data from any other running program owned by the same user, because debugging implies reading and writing the program's memory. More or less the only way to prevent this is to prevent that the PC gets infected by malware.

This is completely independent of the program language used.

Comment: So, the risk of a program attempting to search for memory improperly cleared by the GC _would_ technically be the same type of program that tries to compromise the memory during runtime, which would be unpreventable by the author of the program; I understand now.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point. Of course, this implies your program has no obvious data-leaks on its own (like sending the password over network in plain text)