# Can GC copy byte arrays?

Tags: c#, security, memory

I have a function which generates a random key, like this:

```
internal static char[] GenerateKey(int size) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try
    {
        bytes = new byte[size];
        char[] result = new char[size];

        FillByteArrayWithStuff(bytes); // Fills bytes with some data, nothing more
        FillCharArrayWithBytes(result, bytes); // Fills result with data from bytes, nothing more

        return result;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            Array.Clear(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

All `FillByteArrayWithStuff` does is it fills `bytes` with randomly generated bytes. `FillCharArrayWithBytes` converts data from `bytes` and fills it into `result`.

At the end of the function, I clear `bytes` because it's not needed anymore.
When I finish using `result` from this function, I also clear that `char[]`. The data is used for a `win32` function call.

My question:
Is it possible for `bytes` or any other `byte[]` created using `new` to be copied by the `GC`?

If `byte[]`'s can be copied by the `GC` that means that the array might not be properly zeroed out, and that there still could be copies of the `byte[]` hanging in plain memory.

Comment: You are concerned about security? Or why do you care?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218162/how-can-i-securely-clear-the-contents-of-a-textbox-using-pointers-in-c/67219311#67219311 this answer. Bottom line: It doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, the GC may move memory around. You can avoid this by pinning the data in memory with calling `var gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned)` and later call `GCHandle.Free(gcHandle)`. But of course your data is still readable during the time you fill it and you clear it. Like the others have said if others get access to your processes memory they can do anything to get a hold of sensitive data.

Comment: @ckuri By moving around do you mean the data is copied? Also, it's inevitable the raw data is in memory at one point, because I still have to use the key, but clearing it greatly reduces the odds

Comment: Yes, the GC may copy objects to other locations in order to optimize memory (akin to defragmentation), e.g. copy data from sparsely used memory blocks into the available space of other memory blocks so that it can return memory with no data back to the OS and reduce the applications memory footprint. As far as I know the GC only clears data when you request memory from it, but not when it frees or moves an object.

Comment: In recent versions of C#, leveraging `Span` allows you to shift a great deal of the burden of checking the memory does not escape to the compiler, as it ensures it will at least not leave the stack. Note that, for reasons mentioned by others, trying to zealously manage memory is in typically not worth it compared to ensuring the machine's memory is never read by rogue processes in the first place. It can be used as a defense in depth strategy, but you're starting off with a handicap if you're using managed code. (Try ensuring memory is not swapped to disk, for example -- very hard.)

Comment: The answer is yes it might be copied. You can use EncryptedString to address this too.